# Django modal display based on the class id list

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, bootstrap-modal

I would like to allow the modal to be displayed on the basis of the id set from the database. Having different fruit/vegetables displayed in the container divided into tiles, I put their id in the id field of the class.

In other words, pressing a button in the overlay class for a particular fruit displays a single modal with the rest of the information.

**HTML CODE:**

```
{% block body_block %}
<div class="container-fruits">
    <div class="row">
        {% for t in thumb %}
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 box">
                {% thumbnail t.image "255x189" crop="center" as im %}
                    <div class="hovereffect">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ im.url }}" alt="Card image cap">
                        <div class="overlay">
                            <h2>{{ t.name }}</h2>
                            <a id="{{ t.id }}" class="info" data-target="#{{ t.id }}" href="#">show details</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endthumbnail %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>

{% for t in thumb %}
    <div id="{{ t.id }}" class="fruitsModal" tabindex="-1" style="display: none">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg ">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h2 class="modal-title">{{ t.name }} information</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h2 class="modal-body-text">{{ t.description }}</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}

<script src="{% static 'javascript/fruits.js' %}"></script>

{% endblock %}
```

**Javascript/Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.info').click(function (e) {
    $(".fruitsModal").fadeIn('slow');
    var image = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('src');
    var text = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('t.name');
    $(".img-responsive").attr("src", image);
    $(".modal-body").attr("modal-body-text", text);
    console.log('hello bind');

});
$(".btn-default").click(function () {
    $(".fruitsModal").fadeOut('slow');
});
});
```

Comment: so what is wrong is your code? what do you want to do?

Comment: as i mention in topic. What I would like to achieve is: after click for specific button in overlay class, who represent single fruit  open only one modal for exacly this fruit. With the same id.

Comment: check my answer and let me know!

Answer (score 3):

To open the modal targeted by a specific ID, you just need to know the ID and

- Remove the `id` `id="{{ t.id }}"` from your `a` tag
- Rename your target `data-target="#modal-{{ t.id }}"` to make it a little better to avoid multiple identical `id`s.

  ```
  <a data-toggle="modal" class="info" data-target="#modal-{{ t.id }}"....
  ```
- Finally rename the `id` of your modals, like the target above

  ```
  <div id="modal-{{ t.id }}" class="fruitsModal" tabindex="-1" style="display: none">
  ```

The tag `a` becomes:

```
<a class="info" data-target="#modal-{{ t.id }}" href="#">show details</a>
```

And the modal:

```
<div id="modal-{{ t.id }}" class="fruitsModal" tabindex="-1" style="display: none">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg ">
```

**1st Option**:

If you need to let bootstrap do everything for you, means when you click on `a` without your script, `the modal` will show up.

Just add the `data-toggle` attribute to your `a` tag, and add the same value of `data-target` to `href`.

```
    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#modal-{{ t.id }}" data-target="#modal-{{ t.id }}"
```

> In that case, the `data-target=""` is not really needed

**2nd option**:

As you want to do some stuff before showing the modal, this fits your need.
When triggering the `a` tag with `click` event, is js,  you just need to show the concerned modal

```
    $('.info').click(function (e) {
        $(".fruitsModal").fadeIn('slow');
        var image = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('src');
        var text = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('t.name');
        $(".img-responsive").attr("src", image);
        $(".modal-body").attr("modal-body-text", text);
        console.log('hello bind');
        // # retrieve the target modal: data-target="#modal-{{ t.id }}"
        var t_modal = $("this").data('target');
        $(t_modal).show(); // this is because you have style={display:none}
        $(t_modal).modal('show');
    });
```

Comment: When I try 1st solution it contains the changes for specific id's in address for example: http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/products/#modal-5 when I am clicking for specific fruit, but modal doesn't show up. Contain the 2nd option show up all the modals, when click on any specific id in overlay class. And maybe its important but when I use javascript with this fragment:
`var t_modal = $("this").data('target');
    $(t_modal).show(); // this is because you have style={display:none}
    $(t_modal).modal('show');`
it show up error **Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function**